# Plot ordiellipse from vegan in ggplot2 example not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, vegan

I'm trying to plot a pca biplot in ggplot with ellipsoids for groups, and I found an example in
[this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794419/plotting-ordiellipse-function-from-vegan-package-onto-nmds-plot-created-in-ggplo#_=_).

However, I can't reproduce the result. I ran both versions of Didzis Elfer's solution, but the `df_ell` dataframe remains empty. When I run the last command:

```
ggplot(data = NMDS, aes(MDS1, MDS2)) + geom_point(aes(color = group)) +
geom_path(data=df_ell, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2,colour=group), size=1, linetype=2)
```

I get the following error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'NMDS1' not found`

So it seems the function doesn't work. Does it have to do with the most recent version of the vegan package?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Very late, but i was running into the same problem.

Check if `levels(NMDS$group)` returns NULL.
Converting your grouping variable from character to factor did fix the problem for me. In Didzis Elfer's solution a simple

```
NMDS$group <- as.factor(NMDS$group)
```

was enough to get the function running.